# How to pass data to BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I am showing data in `RecyclerView`. When i click on list item launching `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

How to pass list item data to BottomSheetDialogFragment in kotlin

```
 BottomSheetFragment().show(context!!.supportFragmentManager, "BottomSheetFragment")

class BottomSheetFragment() : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coin_detail_lauout, container, false)
        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

use `Bundle`

```
    val bottomSheetFragment = BottomSheetFragment()
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("key", data)
    bottomSheetFragment.arguments = bundle
```

on `ViewHolder` Class

```
 inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val textView = itemView.textView!!

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            showBottomSheet(itemView.context, list.get(layoutPosition))
        }
    }

    private fun showBottomSheet(context: Context, data: String) {

        val bottomSheetFragment = BottomSheetFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("key", data)
        bottomSheetFragment.arguments = bundle

        bottomSheetFragment.show(
            (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager,
            "bottomSheetFragment"
        )
    }

}
```

inside `onCreateView` of your `BottomSheetFragment`

```
arguments?.getString("key")
```

`BottomSheetFragment` class

```
class BottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottomsheetfragment_list_dialog, container, false)
    val data =  arguments?.getString("key")
//  Log.d("===",data+"")
    return view
    }

}
```